# Converting to manifest version 3 an open source extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm having trouble converting this extension to version 3, can someone help me

https://github.com/Fastbyte01/Deletecy

the extension get a json file from GitHub and pass it to the extension

have different types of errors in chrome console and the extension don't loading.
Tried different things but have error on service worker don't working and local storage